The user can enter any date format in the date column, but I have to save it in a format like "yyyy-mm-dd"
different date formats but the code should be able to accept any date format such as Friday, 29 May 2015. 

I had created a common function in which I have added custom date format but this format is Friday, May 29, 2015. It is not allowing.
Please help if anyone has any idea let me know because I have never worked on date and I am not able to find any solution.
I try below common function for convert date input to one format
public DateTime ParseDateAndTime(string dd)
    {
        //    string dd = "12/31/2015"; //or 31/12/2015
      string c=  DateTime.ParseExact(dd, "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DateTime startDate;
        string[] formats = {
            "dd/MM/yyyy",
            "dd/M/yyyy",
            "d/M/yyyy",
            "d/MM/yyyy",
            "dd/MM/yy",
            "dd/M/yy",
            "d/M/yy",
            "d/MM/yy",
            "M/d/yyyy",
             "M/d/yyyy",
            "MM.d.yyyy",
            "dddd dd MMMM yyyy",
            "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy",
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",
            "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
            "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm",
            "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt",
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "MMMM dd",
            "yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK",
            "ddd, dd MMM yyy HH’:’mm’:’ss ‘GMT’",
            "yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss",
            "yyyy MMMM",
            "MMMM dd, yyyy",
            "dd.MM.yyyy",
            "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
        };
        DateTime.TryParseExact(dd, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate);

        return DateTime.Parse(startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }


Quick question - is 01/05/2024 in May or January? Either could be correct, and without guessing, neither we nor any code you write will be able to know for sure.

Also, where possible, don't store it formatted at all. Parse it to a DateTime once early on in input and then just use DateTime types throughout the rest of the code. Don't let anything turn it back into a string until you're displaying the value back to the user.

but this code is giving error  DateTime.ParseExact(dd, "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

You've jumped straight into coding without thinking about the problem first, and realising you won't be able to solve the problem. There are multiple date formats which produce identical strings for different dates. You cannot take those strings and unambiguously work out what the user meant. Instead of trying to solve an unsolvable problem, give the user an input control that lets them unambiguously specify the date they mean and work with that.
